# How to read KeyPair values from a text file and add it to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Below is the that works, but I would like to call all those KeyValuePair from an external file. What is the best possible way to read KeyValuePair line by line from an external text file? The external file I would like to put in App_Data folder in Visual Studio.

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>() {

       { "TitleOne", "ABC"},
       { "TitleTwo", "FGD"},
       { "TitleThree", "NKL"},
       { "TitleFour", "WER"},
}
```

Comment: Please show us the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
Dictionary<String,String> dict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
using( StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( File.Open("filename.txt") ) ) {

    String line;
    while( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null ) {

        // assuming that values are not surrounded in quotes and are separated by a space character:

        Int32 spaceIdx = line.IndexOf(' ');
        if( spaceIdx == 0 || spaceIdx == -1 ) continue; // skip invalid lines

        String key   = line.Substring( 0, spaceIdx - 1 );
        String value = line.Substring( spaceIdx );

        dict.Add( key, value );
    }
}
```

If your keys will have spaces in them, you will need to use a simple parser (such as a simple state-machine reader, or regular-expression).

As my code splits on only the first space character there is no need to call `String.Split` because then spaces in the `value` portion would be lost - and you'd incur extra memory and runtime cost for allocating the new substrings.